# XMLReader in SilverLight - URI prefix is not recognized, error occurs outside Visual Studio

Tags: xml, silverlight, xmlreader

I've wrote this and it works perfectly when I debug this via VS:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Uri url = new Uri("meble.xml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
        client.DownloadStringAsync(url);
    }


    void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            StringReader stream = new StringReader(e.Result);
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
            string id = String.Empty;
            string nazwa = String.Empty;
            string cena = String.Empty;
            string imgsrc = String.Empty;
            List<string> parametry = new List<string>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //dostuff
            }

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message.ToString());
        }
```

I've got .xml file in same dir as .xap file. However when I move both .xap and .xml to dir where my .html page is, I'm getting: an error occured during a WebClient request. URI prefix is not recognized. Any ideas what should I do? Tried various ways to change UriKind, build action as Resource for .xml file but none works...

Answer (score 1):

Make the **Hosting application** as startup project.